# python list all webpages with a special image

Tags: python, image, web-scraping

I want to create a list of all pages with this image (image.png).
I did the following, what do I need to change?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getdata(url):
r=request.get(url)
return r.text

data = getdata ("https://url")
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

image_links = soup.find_all('img', {'src': 'image.png'})
print (imgae_links)
```

Comment: `soup.find_all('img', {'src': 'url_of_image.png'})`

Comment: thanks. but if I print it's still []

Comment: show url, which one u trying to scrap

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I changed the urls.

Answer (score -2):

I think you want to scrape a javascript website you can use selenium or any library
[see this](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).